# Search and print with input data python-postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to make an application that the user enters an item and searches the database and prints the result.

```
book = input("Give me book-name")
cur.execute('''select isbn,tittle_books,name_publisher,book_available from books where book_available = %s ''',(book,))
print("\nSelecting rows from books table using cursor.fetchall")

records = cur.fetchall()

print("\nPrint each row and it's columns values\n")
for row in records:
    print("isbn =", row[0],)
    print("tittle_books = ", row[1])
    print("name_publisher = ", row[2])
    print("book_available = ", row[3],"\n---------------")
```

The above code does not show me the results

Comment: An issue that I can see is you are doing an exact lookup, `book_available = %s`. So if book name returned from the `input` is not exact you will find anything. Solving this would be easier if you provided an example of the data input, the query that was actually generated and any possible errors that showed up in the Postgres logs.

Comment: This is result 
Give me book-name Raven

Selecting rows from books table using cursor.fetchall

Print each row and it's columns values

PostgreSQL connection is closed

Comment: Yes, but does the exact name Raven exist in the `books` table? In other words in `psql` does `select isbn,tittle_books,name_publisher,book_available from books where book_available = 'Raven'` return anything?

Comment: Yes, it is in my database and as a result I will not get anything.

Comment: I'm not understanding. Do you get a result when you run the query in `psql`?

Comment: Yes, I got the right results in psql.

Comment: So you need to verify what is in `book` exactly. I'm guessing there is extra white space that is throwing the `book_available =` off.